# Drawing lines between nodes using CSS

Tags: html, css

Am hardly finding right words to describe the challenge i have in hand. I have set of nodes arranged in Organizational Chart way. I want to know if there is a way to connect those nodes through lines and these lines should be dynamic - may be drawing them using CSS would be right way.

[image]

Things look similar to what's been shown in pic.

Along with way to draw lines that connects nodes i would be happy to know if there is a more efficient way to generate those nodes dynamically like `<ul>` and `<li>` structure.

Following is the code snippet i have used to generate above image (which has very minimal usage of Bootstrap):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Oval</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                padding-top: 20px;
            }

            .oval {
                width: 400px;
                height: 160px;
                background: #5fa2dd;
                border-radius: 50%;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .circle {
                width: 190px;
                height: 190px;
                background: #9cc96b;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }

            .emptyrow{
                margin : 50px 0;
            }

            .med-circle{
                width: 150px;
                height: 150px;
                background: #9cc96b;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 oval"><p>key1 : value1</p><p>key2 : value2</p><p>key3 : value3</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row emptyrow">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2 circle"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2 circle"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2 circle"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Question in nutshell :

1. Better way to generate nodes dynamically
2. How to draw lines to connect those nodes ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/siiron/pen/aLkdE

Comment: There is also this option: http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with SVG.

With that you can do pretty much anything you want, lines included, which CSS will have much more difficulties to handle

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/gfpj1xjb/4/)

Stack snippet

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100vmin;
}
.shadow {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) );
          filter: drop-shadow( 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) );
}
.line {
  stroke: gray;
}
.ellipse {
  fill: lightblue;
}
.circle {
  fill: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="395" height="305" viewBox="0 0 395 305" class="shadow">
  <line x1="195" y1="70" x2="50" y2="200" stroke-width="1" class="line"/>
  <line x1="195" y1="70" x2="195" y2="200" stroke-width="1" class="line"/>
  <line x1="195" y1="70" x2="340" y2="200" stroke-width="1" class="line"/>
      
  <ellipse cx="195" cy="70" rx="120" ry="70" class="ellipse"/>
  <text x="50%" y="70" text-anchor="middle" dy=".3em">Some text...</text>
  
  <circle cx="50" cy="250" r="50" class="circle"/>
  <text x="50" y="250" text-anchor="middle" dy=".3em">Some text...</text>
  
  <circle cx="195" cy="250" r="50" class="circle"/>
  <text x="195" y="250" text-anchor="middle" dy=".3em">Some text...</text>

  <circle cx="340" cy="250" r="50" class="circle"/>
  <text x="340" y="250" text-anchor="middle" dy=".3em">Some text...</text>
</svg>
```